# How to Open File and then Activate that Window in VBA (Microsoft Word)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have one Word Document ("Template1") opened already. I am trying to write the VBA code to open a Word Document file ("FileWithData") and copy the information from "FileWithData" into "Template1". "FileWithData" could be any file and that is the reason I am using OpenDialog.

Everything is working but I am stuck when it comes to Activating "FileWithData" window to start "Copying and Pasting" process.

```
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'if the user selects a file
If intChoice <> 0 Then
'get the path selected
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
'opens the document
objWord.Documents.Open (strPath)


 FileName = objWord.ActiveDocument.Name
```

and here it breaks :(

```
Windows(FileName).Activate
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Page1"
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = True
End With
Selection.Copy

Windows("Template1").Activate
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Page1"
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = True
End With
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
```

I am getting the following error: 
Run-time error "5941"

The requested member of the collection does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of factors in play with this code that will or might cause problems.

The reason for the error is that this code is running in Excel, so if `objWord` is not used for Word syntax, and both Word and Excel use the same name for an object, VBA will try to use the Excel object model. In this case, as the file is in Word and not Excel, using `objWord.Windows(Filename).Activate` should avoid this particular error.

Other considerations:

As with Excel, using `Active`, `Activate` or `Selection` in Word VBA is unreliable and shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary. Better to work with the application's objects, directly. So declare and instantiate a variable for the Word document and use that instead of `ActiveDocument`:

```
Dim objDoc as Object 'Word.Document
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)

FileName = objDoc.Name
```

It's unsure whether you'd really need to activate this window. It's not necessary for manipulating a document's content via VBA. If it's in order to show it to the user, for editing, then by all means. I might wait until the end of the code, but that would be personal preference... In any case, it's possible to address the document's windows, specifically, rather than having VBA search for it:

```
objDoc.Windows(1).Activate
```

In order to transfer formatted content from one place (`Range`) in any document to another place (`Range`) in the same or another document, using bookmarks can be done in one step, without any selecting or activating:

```
objDoc.Bookmarks("Page1").Range.FormattedText = _
       objWord.Documents("Template1").Bookmarks("Page1").Range.FormattedText
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am working only with Word (not using Excel at all). I liked the last section of your reply. You are right, I do not really need to activate the window. I am using the code but it is giving me a Bad File Name error.
    Template1 = ActiveDocument.Name
    <code snipped in the question>
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)
    FileWithData = objDoc.Name             
    objDoc.Documents(FileWithData).Bookmarks("Page1").Range.FormattedText 
    = _       
    objWord.Documents(Template1).Bookmarks("Page1").Range.FormattedText

Comment: @AyupovSukhrab In what application is this code running, then? You included the tag excel-vba in the original question. Since the code uses `CreateObject` I had no reason to question that...

Comment: the code is running in MS Word only. My apologies, I removed the tag excel-vba.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to copy data from a Word doc into Excel.  Is that right?  The code below will do this for you.  Just change the path to the Word file that you are referencing, and change the ranges, if need be.

```
Sub Copy_From_Word()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Disable all the Alerts from excel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'After opening Word Doc, Document will not be visible
    'Create a New Object for Microsoft Word Application
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    'Create a New Word Document Object
    Dim objDoc As New Word.Document
    'Open a Word Document and Set it to the newly created object above
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Open("C:\path_here\your_document.docx")
    'To Store all the content of that word Document in a variable
    strTemp = objDoc.Range(0, objDoc.Range.End)
    'Now store that variable value in to a cell range
    Range("A1").Value = strTemp
    str1 = objDoc.Range(0, 1)
    Range("A2").Value = str1
    Range("B2").Value = strTemp

    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    objWord.Quit

End Sub
```